# BluetoothSocket.connect() throws IOException while app is running in background thread

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I'm working on Bluetooth application in which I'm trying to connect one of the Bluetooth devices(paired) which have been scanned by Bluetooth adapter. I'm trying to connect BluetoothSocket.connect() inside background service thread, but it throws IOException: 'read failed, socket might be closed or timeout, read ret: -1' every time.

I'm referring Android [BluetoothChat Sample GitHub](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat/#readme) sample code. In BluetoothChat project BluetoothSocket.connect() works properly when the app is in the foreground, but when the app in the background it gives me the same exception.

```
BluetoothDevice btDevice = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(address); //address = "98:0C:A5:CF:34:8B"
connect(btDevice, true);
```

```
    public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure) {
        // Cancel any thread
        if (connectThread != null) {
            connectThread.cancel();
            connectThread = null;
        }

        // Start the thread to connect with the given device
        connectThread = new ConnectThread(device, secure);
        connectThread.start();
    }
```

```
 // Unique UUID for this application
    private static final UUID MY_UUID_SECURE =
            UUID.fromString("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");
    private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE =
            UUID.fromString("8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66");

    // runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection
    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket socket;
        private String socketType;

        private ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure) {
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            socketType = secure ? "Secure" : "Insecure";
            try {
                if (secure) {
                    tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_SECURE,
                            MY_UUID_SECURE);
                } else {
                    tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(
                            NAME_INSECURE, MY_UUID_INSECURE);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(BluetoothWebSocket.class.getSimpleName(), "bt connect: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            socket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            setName("ConnectThread" + socketType);

            // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
            BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().cancelDiscovery();

            // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
            try {
                socket.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(BluetoothWebSocket.class.getSimpleName(), "bt connection error: " + e.getMessage());
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    Log.e(BluetoothWebSocket.class.getSimpleName(), "bt connection IO error: " + e2.getMessage());
                }
                btConnectResult = "{\"bt_connection_result\":\"failed\"}"; //scanned result failed
                return;
            }
            btConnectResult = "{\"bt_connection_result\":\"success\"}"; //scanned result success
        }

        boolean cancel() {
            try {
                socket.close();
                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(BluetoothWebSocket.class.getSimpleName(), "bt connection cancel error: " + e.getMessage());
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
```

If anyone has any idea how to solve this issue, please share.
TIA.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?